# How to display UIActivityIndicator in the center of the NavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, activity-indicator

i want to display my Activity Indicator in the center of the Navigation Bar.
At the Moment its on the rightBarButtonItem.

How can this be done?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to add a `UIActivityIndicatorView` on top of your navigation bar, and show/hide it as needed.

Answer (score 6):

here's another way to insert a custom UIView directly into the UINavigationBar with UINavigationItem's property:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *titleView
```

and where navController is the UINavigationController that your view (managed by UINavigationbar) is in...

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *aView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];

navController.navigationItem.titleView = aView;
[aView release];
```

should do the trick